# Group by Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, case-when

I have the following tables Issue, IssueStatus and CustomTable(CT) .Following are the data in the same

```
Issue:                       Issuestatus:                    CT

Issue|pkey|issuestatus       id | pname                     Issue|Referred
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
100     T-1  1                  1   Open                       100     NULL
200     T-2  2                  2   Closed                     200     NULL 
300     T-3  3                  3   Acknowledged               700     Dev
400     T-4  4                  4   In Progress                800     QA
500     T-5  1                  5   Referred                   800     NULL 
600     T-6  2                                                 400     NULL
700     T-7  5                                                 500     NULL   
800     T-8  5                                                 700     NULL
```

I need the output like the following

```
pname      |  Count
Open           2
Closed         2
Acknowledged   1
In Progress    1
Dev            1 
QA             1
```

hence if you see, need to group by `issuestatus` and get the count of `pkey`, however when the `issuestatus` is "Referred", you need to look in CT Table and get the corresponding  Referred Column Text in the group by. The issue in CT is linked to issue in Issue table.

This is what I had tried , but not the right output

```
select pname = case 
    when pname='Referred' then CT.Referred 
    else pname end,
    COUNT(pkey) 
from  CT,issue a,issuestatus
where a.issuestatus=issuestatus.id and a.issue=CT.ISSUE 
group by pname,CT.Referred
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested following query giving exactly what you want

Try it

```
WITH T1 AS (
  SELECT (CASE WHEN pname='Referred' THEN Referred ELSE pname END)AS [pn]
  FROM (SELECT i.Issue,c.Referred,iss.pname
        FROM Issue i
        INNER JOIN IssueStatus iss ON i.issuestatus=iss.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CT c ON c.Issue=i.Issue
       ) t
)


SELECT pn,count(*) AS cnt
FROM T1
WHERE pn IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY pn
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6cdd/73)

Comment: Is this SQL Server compatible

Comment: @Alfaromeo Query is edited,first query was compatible with mysql.Try this for sql server,I change 'case when' instead of if.

Comment: Me getting in CT.Referred "mutipart identifier could not be found

Comment: @Alfaromeo use c.Referred instead of CT.Referred

Comment: @Alfaromeo,Sorry because i don't have sql server for testing but query logic is perfect so test it and reply me.

Comment: Hmm, but not sure getting multipart identifier error now almost in c.Issue 4th line ,c.Referred 2nd line and first line c.referred

Comment: @Alfaromeo Query is edited and Query is now sql server compatible.check the sql fiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT pname, COUNT(pname)
    FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN Pname='Referred'  THEN CT.referred else st.pname END)AS pname
            FROM Issue a JOIN IssueStatus st
            ON a.issuestatus = st.id LEFT OUTER JOIN CT
            ON a.Issue = CT.Issue) tbl
    GROUP BY pname
    HAVING pname IS NOT NULL;
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6cdd/84)

Comment: Dude , this outputs data of Dev and QA alone group count . It doesn't output rest of the status

Comment: The CT table can actually contain value for Referred for issues that are also not in Referred Status.Have updated the Fiddle, please check and the output is weiry

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Haven't tested it because there are not scripts of test data.

```
   select case when pname='Referred' then CT.Referred else pname end pname, COUNT(*) cnt
    from  CT,issue a,issuestatus
    where a.issuestatus=issuestatus.id and a.issue=CT.ISSUE 
    group by case when pname='Referred' then CT.Referred else pname end
```